# Replace child component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Look at this component (call it `app-parent`):

```
<div class="child1">
  <!-- A lot of common stuff -->
  ...
</div>

<div class="child2">
  <app-custom-child-component>
    <!-- A lot of customized stuff -->
    ...
  </app-custom-child-component>
</div>
```

So it has two children, `child1` is shared across all components, `child2` has a custom component and is different from place to place.

I'd like to use `app-parent` multiple times and at the same time be able to customize `app-custom-child-component` (and other things related to `child2`), but do not want to duplicate `child1` (both UI and logic behind it, that's coupled with `child2`).

Think: any header - body (and perhaps footer as additional `child3`) relationship.

I could not find examples of this, does that mean that's not supported or recommended? If this is OK, is there an example? If not, what's the alternative?

Comment: What about `child2` is different? Does it vary by route?

Comment: did you look at `ng-content`

Comment: @stealththeninja It varies by the custom usage of the component. E.g. I can have a page with 5 instances of `app-parent` where each of `child2` has a different configuration. Here are some different examples: 1) different columns of a table 2) forms with different (auto-generated) fields 3) context-dependent menu entries. Routes are not involved in this case, but certainly it can be the case.

Comment: @RahulSingh I did not, let me look into that.